# Subnetting - Am I doing this right?

Tags: networking, subnet

I'm planning my first network with 2 subnets and came up with the following schema:

[image]

I'd like to know...

- Would this work?
- Did I use the right amount of routers?
- Did I configure everything correctly?
- Plus, do I need to configure static routing here, so that every host within the subnets has internet access?

Comment: Why are you subnetting the 192.168.2.0 network? Why not use 192.168.2.0 and 192.168.3.0?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know...

> Would this work?

Yes

> Did I use the right amount of routers?

Subjective, as you could do the same thing with a single router

> Did I configure everything correctly?

Again a little subjective, if you could explain why you are splitting them like this it would help more.

> Plus, do I need to configure static routing here, so that every host within the subnets has internet access?

Depending on the router it might need a static route or just a gateway defined. Do you want to access anything between the subnets, because then you will need static routes.

Comment: Thank you, it is appreciated. One more question: When configuring a host within a subnet. What do I put as Gateway and DNS? I'd say the IP of the Subnet Router, not the Router which is outside the Subnets. Is that correct?

Comment: About static routing: I'd like to access a network printer within subnet 1 from the hosts within subnet 2. Can you give me a hint how to approach this? I never did static routing, but I'd guess I need to place a route in the router of Subnet 2 pointing first to the outside router (which is in no subnets) then to the router of subnet 1 and then to the printer IP. Is that about right? Also, do i put the full route in the first router in subnet 2 or is more like I tell each device to "forward" the route to the next point?

Comment: You would need to make a choice 'where' to do the routing. You could put a route on the sub net router pointing to the other subnet router and vice versa (packets need to get back) or you could put the routes on the router/modem. Depends on make etc.... Route Subnet 2 to IP on subnet 1. Not the whole range.